# Cannot add property to an outer object from function scope?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have a function that gives me a socket object inside the io.on() function. However when i try to give a new property to its object inside a socket.on function, i am unable to use the property outside the socket.on function. 
The console shows me this -

```
roomName
#undefined
```

I want to know how can i use the property outside the object also.

```js
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
 socket.on("join_group", function(user, roomnum) {
  socket.userName = user;
  socket.selfRoom = roomnum;
  socket.join(roomnum);
  console.log(socket.selfRoom);
 });
    socket.on("msg", function() {
 console.log("#" + socket.selfRoom);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know how can i use the property outside the object also.

You are setting the property to outside object `socket` in the callback function to `on` event.

But by the time `on` event-handler is invoked, outside `console.log("#" + socket.selfRoom);` statement has already been executed.

Please note that

- **Defining** the event handler `socket.on("join_group", function(user, roomnum) {` **is not same** as this event handler (callback method) being invoked.
- JavaScript is single threaded and work on **event-loop** model, so when the event is fired this event-handler has gone to a **event-loop queue** which will be executed after the **current task + task already in queue**.

Comment: I am sorry, I have edited my question. Please have a look. I actually wanted to know how can i add properties to an outer object from inside another function, such that those properties are not confined to the scope of the function.

Comment: @DhruvChadha it is not confined to scope of the function, it is set to the same object only.

Comment: Then why am i getting #undefined (please take a look at the edited code) ?

Comment: @DhruvChadha the output will depend on which event is getting fired first. Can you try doing the opposite way to test your theory?